# Python: subprocess.Popen and subprocess.call hang

Tags: python

I have a problem using the subprocess.Popen or subprocess.call when I use them to execute a command lines that generates a lot of output, the python scripts hangs, but what is weird that  after waiting for a while, while the script is in its hanging state, I find that the job commanded by the cmd line has been done, and only the script is hung out.

```
subprocess.call(cmd, shell = True)
#OR
subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stdin = subprocess.PIPE, shell = True)
# HANGS HERE
print "show something after subprocess"
```

Note that the last print is never executed, but actually the cmd has been executed.

Note also the cmd is related to the serial port, so when I plug out the serial cable, everything become fine, and the last print statetement get executed. But when I use the terminal everything is fine even if the serial is plugged in, it only occurs with the python script.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 18):

According to the python documentation, `subprocess.call` runs the command and waits for it to complete, so it's equivalent to `subprocess.Popen` followed by `Popen.wait`.

However, the `Popen.wait` method documentation explicitly warns about the problem of buffer overflow and recommends to use `Popen.communicate` instead. Hence, the solution you're looking for should be something like:

```
import subprocess
process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
stdout, stderr = process.communicate()
print "show something after subprocess"
```

Comment: There's no problem using `subprocess.call` if you don't use `subprocess.PIPE`, which the OP isn't.

Comment: It does not explain why the output of the `print` statement is not shown in the parent. `Popen()` does not wait for the child even if the child process is blocked in an attempt to write to the pipe with the full buffer.

Comment: Just to add... if somebody needs the `returncode`, this can be accessed in the above case via `process.returncode`. Unlike `wait()` this is not returned as a return value with `communicate()`, which returns a tuple (stdout, stderr)

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why your first line doesn't work - as there are no `stdin`/`stdout`/`stderr` redirections, there is no need for blocking.

The second one is supposed to block if the process

1. expects data via stdin or
2. sends more data to stdout than a pipe can hold wothout being read.

But as your subprocess terminates correctly, I cannot see a reason for blocking as well. Are you sure that it really terminates?