# Correctly getting return code when issuing command over SSH via subprocess

Tags: python, shell, ssh, subprocess

I'm trying to issue a command over ssh and get its return code via subprocess. I have some code that looks like this:

```
cmd = 'ssh user@ip_addr "some_command"'
res = subprocess.check_output(
    cmd,
    shell=True,
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Now this works great if the cmd only generates an exit code (for instance, setting cmd to "exit 1", and then doing a try/catch to see if it exits with a non-zero. However, the following hangs indefinitely:

```
cmd = 'ssh user@ip_addr "ls -la && exit 0;"'
res = subprocess.check_output(
    cmd,
    shell=True,
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

I saw [two questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18273962/python-subprocess-call-hangs) that [looked similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8077868/python-subprocess-popen-and-subprocess-call-hang), and I [did RTFM](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html), but I'm still not sure what to do. I don't really care whether or not the command generates output; I'm more concerned with the exit code. If anyone knows what the best way of doing this is, or whether or not I'm using subprocess inappropriately, I would appreciate it.

Comment: `check_output` doesn't seem to have a `stdout` argument. Did you mean `stderr` there?

Comment: I did, sorry about that.

Comment: Then you need to see the big notice about **not** using `stderr=PIPE` because it might hang on the link you pointed at.

Comment: have you by any chance run the 2nd command in a different environment where `ssh` might have been waiting for the password from you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `stdout=subprocess.PIPE`, and it should work; `check_output` itself captures the output, so redirecting it using `stdout=subprocess.PIPE` will cause problems. If you don't care about the output at all, just use `subprocess.check_call` (and again, don't use `stdout=subprocess.PIPE`).

Comment: `stdout=PIPE` does not correspond to the behavior described in the question. `stdout=PIPE` leads to *immediate* `ValueError`, not *"the following hangs indefinitely"* -- OP hasn't shown us the actual code. If it is `stderr=PIPE` then the process may hang if it fills its stderr OS pipe buffer (~65K on my machine e.g., `call(['python3', '-c', 'import sys; print("a"*10**4, file=sys.stderr)'], stderr=PIPE)` doesn't hang). I don't see how `ls -la` would generate ~65K error message on stderr.

Answer (score 0):

DO NOT USE `std{out,err}=PIPE` UNLESS YOU READ FROM THE PIPE!!!

To get the return code while *discarding* the output of a command issued over ssh using `subprocess` module:

```
from subprocess import call, DEVNULL, STDOUT

returncode = call(['ssh', 'user@ip', 'ls -la && exit 0;'],
                  stdin=DEVNULL, stdout=DEVNULL, stderr=STDOUT)
```

See also, [How to hide output of subprocess in Python 2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11269575/4279).

Note: `shell=True` is not used.